# My condition doesn't show negative values ​between 0 and -1 in rdlc reports from .net in c #

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, report-viewer2016

In visual studio 2019 .rdlc (report viewer) reports, I add a condition so that one of the decimal fields of the report is not displayed in case its value is 0. The condiction is:

=IIf(Val(Fields!Fluctuacion.Value)=0,"",Fields!Fluctuacion.Value)

So far it works fine, the value is shown only when its value is other than 0. But there is a little case where it doesn't work well and it doesn't show when it should show.

This case occurs when the fluctuation has a negative value between 0 and -1, for example: -0.2 If the fluctuation value is -0.2 it is not shown when it should be shown because 0.2 is different from 0 .

Has anyone encountered this problem? How have you solved it?

Thank you.

Greetings.

Comment: This is most likely a rounding issue, does 0.2 do the same?

Comment: 0.2 does not do the same, 0.2 is displayed correctly

Comment: Have you checked whether you're dealing with a signed vs unsigned data type and also whether the data type correctly supports fractions?